# How to start creating a turn based metro game on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, game-center

I was wondering if there is something similar available for Windows Store apps to create multi-player turn based metro games. With client side and server side components

This would be something similar to Game Center that Apple provides provides on the iOS platform.

I am looking for the name of the technology and a sample, if possible!

Comment: Windows Store games use Xbox LIVE for multiplayer, achievements, leaderboards, etc, just like Apple's Game Center.

Comment: Thanks. This is a starting point. I am trying to find out what are the libraries inside Xbox Live that would be helping me to implement such a turn based game for Windows 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following presentation to be usefull:

- [Xbox LIVE on Windows Deep Dive](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29205)

From this I found out that XBox live offers a REST based API to store game state, matchmaking, status, achivements, game messages.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but the internal parts of the turn based game would be the same regardless of if it was a xna, winforms, console, wp7 application, the only thing that would be different would be how the game would be rendered.

So as there probably wont be a specific tutorial telling you how to do this from start to finish, look at a general tutorial for how to make a turn based game and just make it as a command line application at the moment, making sure your game logic is in one project, and your rendering details (console bit) is in another app which just consumes the logic.

This way you can at least start making your game and working out how it should work then when you find out more about metro and how to render things you can just make a new UI project which would again consume your shared game logic and display it in a metro way.

There are plenty of game dev communities out there, so if you look for XNA style turn based games, and just generally think about game design rather than how to display it, you can at least be productive while you wait for an answer.

Comment: Hi Grofit, Thanks for the answer. I was looking specific technologies that let's me to start learning about them! I know now that XBox Live powers the online gaming on Windows 8, now I need to find out how to store games and send status changes of the parties to each other.

Comment: But you are focusing on the wrong things (imo), the fundamentals of your game should be agnostic to the platform your using. Ok you may need to know a bit about C# if you know your targeting .net, but other than that your technologies wont matter too much until you know what your game is going to be. Maybe I am mistaking your question as to be more "How can I create turn based games using windows metro" rather than "What technologies can I used to make server/client based applications in metro", which is still quite a wide open topic.

Comment: I might be not very clear that I am kind of looking for a component that spares me from creating a server backend and can use something made by someone else.